# select to get null value rows for concatination

Tags: oracle, select, with-statement, listagg

Here is the table (TABLE_1)

```
select * from TABLE_1;

PK_1 PK_2 PK_3 PK_4 PK_5 COL_1 COL_2 COL_3
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----- ----- -----
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  1    1     2     3    
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  2    4     5     6    
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  3    7     8     9
```

I want output like this:

```
PK_1 PK_2 PK_3 PK_4 AGGREGATE
---- ---- ---- ---- -------------------
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  123 456 789 000 000
```

So this is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT 
    PK_1 ,PK_2 ,PK_3 ,PK_4 ,
    listagg (COL_1 || COL_2 || COL_3 , ' ')within group (ORDER BY PK_1 ,PK_2 ,PK_3 ,PK_4 , PK_5) as "AGGREGATE"
FROM 
    TABLE_1
GROUP BY
    PK_1 ,PK_2 ,PK_3 ,PK_4
;

PK_1 PK_2 PK_3 PK_4 AGGREGATE
---- ---- ---- ---- -----------
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  123 456 789
```

The problem is that I am not getting the `000 000` output because the data is missing for 4th and 5th rows. I need this query to output `AGGREGATE` column in the format `XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX` BY HAVING `000` if the respective rows are missing according to `PK_5`.

Help Please.. I am thinking this needs a `WITH CLAUSE` but I have no clue to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are expecting a max of 5 rows per (pk_1, pk_2, pk_3, pk_4), then the following (which uses [partition outer join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312)) should do the trick:

```
col aggregate format a20;

with table_1 as (select 'aaa' pk_1, 'bbb' pk_2, 'ccc' pk_3, 'ddd' pk_4, 1 pk_5, 1 col_1, 2 col_2, 3 col_3 from dual union all
                 select 'aaa' pk_1, 'bbb' pk_2, 'ccc' pk_3, 'ddd' pk_4, 2 pk_5, 4 col_1, 5 col_2, 6 col_3 from dual union all
                 select 'aaa' pk_1, 'bbb' pk_2, 'ccc' pk_3, 'ddd' pk_4, 3 pk_5, 7 col_1, 8 col_2, 9 col_3 from dual),
                 -- end of mimicking your table table_1; you wouldn't need this subquery as you already have the table.
       dummy as (select level id
                 from   dual
                 connect by level <= 5)
select   pk_1,
         pk_2,
         pk_3,
         pk_4,
         listagg (nvl(col_1, 0)||nvl(col_2, 0)||nvl(col_3, 0), ' ') within group (order by pk_1, pk_2, pk_3, pk_4, pk_5) aggregate
from   dummy d
       left outer join table_1 t1 partition by (t1.pk_1, t1.pk_2, t1.pk_3, t1.pk_4) on (t1.pk_5 = d.id)
group by pk_1,
         pk_2,
         pk_3,
         pk_4;

PK_1 PK_2 PK_3 PK_4 AGGREGATE           
---- ---- ---- ---- --------------------
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  123 456 789 000 000
```

N.B. If your pk_5 column doesn't start numbering the rows from 1 for each (pk_1, pk_2, pk_3, pk_4) you'll need to use the `row_number()` analytic function to generate the list of numbers to join against the dummy table:

```
with table_1 as (select 'aaa' pk_1, 'bbb' pk_2, 'ccc' pk_3, 'ddd' pk_4, 9 pk_5, 1 col_1, 2 col_2, 3 col_3 from dual union all
                 select 'aaa' pk_1, 'bbb' pk_2, 'ccc' pk_3, 'ddd' pk_4, 10 pk_5, 4 col_1, 5 col_2, 6 col_3 from dual union all
                 select 'aaa' pk_1, 'bbb' pk_2, 'ccc' pk_3, 'ddd' pk_4, 11 pk_5, 7 col_1, 8 col_2, 9 col_3 from dual),
                 -- end of mimicking your table table_1; you wouldn't need this subquery as you already have the table.
       dummy as (select level id
                 from   dual
                 connect by level <= 5),
          t1 as (select pk_1,
                        pk_2,
                        pk_3,
                        pk_4,
                        row_number() over (partition by pk_1, pk_2, pk_3, pk_4 order by pk_5) pk_5,
                        col_1,
                        col_2,
                        col_3
                 from   table_1)
select   pk_1,
         pk_2,
         pk_3,
         pk_4,
         listagg (nvl(col_1, 0)||nvl(col_2, 0)||nvl(col_3, 0), ' ') within group (order by pk_1, pk_2, pk_3, pk_4, pk_5) aggregate
from   dummy d
       left outer join t1 partition by (t1.pk_1, t1.pk_2, t1.pk_3, t1.pk_4) on (t1.pk_5 = d.id)
group by pk_1,
         pk_2,
         pk_3,
         pk_4;

PK_1 PK_2 PK_3 PK_4 AGGREGATE           
---- ---- ---- ---- --------------------
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  123 456 789 000 000
```

Answer (score 1):

Every case covered with this query: missing values in any position, not only at the end. It assumes "AGGREGATE" will always have 5 parts.

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
  SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT LEVEL PK_5 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=5) 
  CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT PK_1, PK_2, PK_3, PK_4 FROM TABLE_1)
), CTE2 AS
(
SELECT PK_1,PK_2,PK_3,PK_4,PK_5 FROM CTE1
)
SELECT PK_1,PK_2,PK_3,PK_4,
LISTAGG (NVL(COL_1, 0) || NVL(COL_2, 0) || NVL(COL_3, 0) , ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PK_1 ,PK_2 ,PK_3 ,PK_4 , PK_5) AS "AGGREGATE"
FROM CTE2 LEFT JOIN TABLE_1 USING(PK_1,PK_2,PK_3,PK_4,PK_5)
GROUP BY
PK_1 ,PK_2 ,PK_3 ,PK_4;
```

Thank you [Boneist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4479309/boneist) for bringing up partition outer join. This is indeed better solution.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 PARTITION BY (PK_1,PK_2,PK_3,PK_4)
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT LEVEL NR FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=5) GEN
  ON GEN.NR = TABLE_1.PK_5
)
SELECT PK_1,PK_2,PK_3,PK_4,
LISTAGG(NVL(COL_1,0) || NVL(COL_2,0) || NVL(COL_3,0), ' ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY PK_1) "AGGREGATE"
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY PK_1, PK_2, PK_3, PK_4;
```

Comment: You could use a [partition outer join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312) instead to avoid the extra join when generating the set of rows. If you don't use that, wouldn't the distinct be better in the `select pk_1, pk_2, pk_3, pk_4 from table_1` subquery, rather than when selecting from the cte1? Less work involved all round that way.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select PK_1 ,PK_2 ,PK_3 ,PK_4, DECODE(length(T.AGG), 11 , CONCAT(T.AGG , ' 000 000'), 15, CONCAT(T.AGG , ' 000'), T.AGG)
from (SELECT 
    PK_1 ,PK_2 ,PK_3 ,PK_4 ,
    listagg (COL_1 || COL_2 || COL_3 , ' ')within group (ORDER BY PK_1 ,PK_2 ,PK_3 ,PK_4 , PK_5) as "AGG"
FROM 
    TABLE_1
GROUP BY
    PK_1 ,PK_2 ,PK_3 ,PK_4
) t;
```

I have written for case where 2 rows are missing. You can edit the decode function to include all cases.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from you question is that whenever you have null in rows of columns Col_1, Col_2 and Col_3 it should be taken as 0 and output should include 000. If this is the case then below query will give the output you are looking for.

```
With a as 
(Select PK_1,PK_2, PK_3, PK_4, PK_5,
       case when col_1 is null then '0' else col_1 end as col_1,
       case when col_2 is null then '0' else col_2 end as col_2,
       case when col_3 is null then '0' else col_3 end as col_3
from table1) 
SELECT PK_1,PK_2,PK_3,PK_4,
     LISTAGG (col_1 || col_2 || col_3, ' ') within group (ORDER BY PK_1 ,PK_2 ,PK_3 ,PK_4 , PK_5) as "AGGREGATE"
    From a
GROUP BY
    PK_1 ,PK_2 ,PK_3 ,PK_4;
```

Comment: that won't work if the rows are missing, as in the OP's case. You'll get a result of "123 456 789" for the OP's data.